# typeof result of 2 undefined variable

Tags: javascript

I just test the "typeof" in javascript, and really don't know why the result is like this.

/************/

```
var cota,
    plouto;

alert(typeof plouto/cota); //NaN
```

/************/

```
var cota,
    plouto;

alert(typeof (plouto/cota)); //number
```

/************/

```
var cota,
    plouto;

var flo = plouto/cota;

alert(typeof flo); //number
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one alerts `NaN` because the `typeof plouto` is executed first, and the result is divided by `cota`. The result of that is not a number, hence `NaN`. You could imagine it like this:

`(typeof plouto) / cota`

The second one divides `plouto` by `cota`, which is not a number (because both variables are `undefined`), but the type of [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) is actually `Number`, which can be confusing!

The same goes for the third example.

Answer (score 3):

The `typeof` operator has precedence over the math operators, so it's executed first.

What you get from `typeof plouto/cota` is first `typeof plouto` then the return value divided with `cota` - resulting in Not A Number. When doing math operation and one of the "participants" is not a number, the whole result will also be NaN.

The other two cases are more simple: the type of NaN is number. Think of that as the equivalent of `null` for objects.